# How to prove analytically $\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan \frac{m}{n}=\arctan \frac{1}{m+n}$ applies to at least all rational numbers?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, proof-writing, angle

Using multiple triangles to find the values of some arctan angles in a trigonometry question so that I could use an exact expression I wondered how could I prove that the following relation applies to all possible rational numbers without using geometry to prove individual case by case:

$\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan \frac{m}{n}=\arctan \frac{1}{m+n}$

[Where the original geometrical thought was](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxAjS.png)

$\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan \frac{1}{2}=\arctan \frac{1}{3}$

$\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan \frac{2}{3}=\arctan \frac{1}{5}$

And lastly, could I use this more widely with complex numbers and if so with what limitations?

Comment: As $\arctan\frac12>\arctan\frac13$, you first equation is clearly false. Come to think of it, so is your second.

Comment: Oh yes, I just noticed I typed + instead of a - sign. Thanks for noticing! So it should be pi per 4 minus the arctan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking here; your equations are wrong. But if $0<m<n$ then
$$\frac\pi4-\arctan\frac mn=\arctan\frac{n-m}{m+n}.$$
In particular,
$$\frac\pi4-\arctan\frac m{m+1}=\arctan\frac{1}{2m+1}$$
so that
$$\frac\pi4-\arctan\frac12=\arctan\frac{1}{3},$$
$$\frac\pi4-\arctan\frac23=\arctan\frac{1}{5},$$
$$\frac\pi4-\arctan\frac34=\arctan\frac{1}{7}$$
etc. Is this what you were aiming at?

Comment: Yes.So in proving it analytically is it all about the relation between m and n?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that 
$$\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{4} - \arctan(\frac{m}{n}) \right) = \frac{n-m}{n+m} $$